# PHP Regex preg_replace multiple values between parentheses

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I am trying to use regular expressions to search through a string, replace several values and build an URL. I have never used regex (from scratch) before so a bit stuck.

The string is contained within [square parentheses] as an identifier. I have tried multiple approaches - I don't understand how to structure the regex or preg_replace method to be able to carry out multiple replacements, ideally without lots of repeat regex lines, but this it the direction I'm trying:

```
    $string= '[mycode="gallery" type="single" id="1" data="only"]'; //INPUT

    $string = preg_replace('/\mycode="(.*)"\]/', '$1/mycode"', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\type="(.*)"\]/', 'mycode_$1.php', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\id="(.*)"\]/', '?id=$1', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\data="(.*)"\]/', '&data=$1', $string);
```

Ultimately to output:

gallery/_mycode_single.php?id=1&data=only (with the [] removed too)

I know that this doesn't work currently as I don't know the method to compile the outputs from the multiple lines; any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, yes - the ] I think was a typo on my part left over from prior efforts. I haven't used preg_replace_callback before - can you elaborate? I assume you mean to use that to get the contents of the [] brackets first, before doing anything else?

Comment: Working using the answer you supplied below - thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to go two layers, first pull everything between the `[]` then replace the values as needed. You can use `preg_replace_callback` 
to accomplish this.

```
$string= '[mycode="gallery" type="single" id="1" data="only"]';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', function($match) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\h*mycode="([^"]+)"\h*/', '$1/mycode', $match[1]);
    $string = preg_replace('/\h*type="([^"]+)"\h*/', 'mycode_$1.php', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\h*id="([^"]+)"\h*/', '?id=$1', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\h*data="([^"]+)"\h*/', '&data=$1', $string);
    return $string;
}, $string);
```

Your regex didn't work for a few reasons:

1. Your strings don't end with `]`
2. Backslashes in regex escape or create meta characters, `\d` is a number `\t` is a tab.
3. If building a URL you don't want a double quote in the returned value
4. You also need to trim the leading and trailing whitespaces

Demo: https://3v4l.org/KDD0B